# Count number of 0s and 1 in Array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Please look these code:

```
 IDlength=128;
 ntags=100;

 Array1 = [ones(ntags, 1), floor(rand(ntags,IDlength-1)*2)];   
 tag_state = zeros(ntags,3); 
 Array1 = unique(Array1,'rows');
```

I want to make new Array with 100 rows (ntags), and 10 columns (100x10): first for number of 1's in every row from Array1, second for number of 0's in every row from `Array1`, and last 8 to present 8 numbers from every row from `Array1`

Comment: the last part is not so clear ("first for number of 1's in every row from Array1, second for number of 0's in every row from Array1, and last 8 to present 8 numbers from every row from Array1"). Can you give us an example of what you want to achieve, please? it will be really easy to answer

Comment: Array1 : 0101101001110111
             1010101011111110
             1111100010101011

I want Array2
             10 6 01110111
             11 5 11111110
             10 6 10101011

10-number of 1's, 6 number of 0s, and 0110111 last 8 number

Comment: @Leos313 could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure that I understood what you want. Precise more if it is not what you are expecting.

```
Array2 = zeros(100,10);
Array2(:,1) = sum(Array1'==1);
Array2(:,2) = sum(Array1'==0);
Array2(:,3:10) = Array1(:,end-7:end);
```